# How to configure geany calltips to have a longer duration?

Tags: ide, geany

The duration for geany is too short, how can I increase the duration that the calltip stays on? Or have geany show the required parameters for a function that stays while I type them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the call tip indefinitely through a key-binding which can be edited in settings.